# Why does the console always say "( was unexpected at this time" when I press "Build" on the Tkinter window?

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to make a software forger but whenever I press "Build" on the Tkinter window the console always say "( was unexpected at this time".
(the problem in the batch script but info in python)

CODE:

Batch:

```
@echo off
if %4 == "''" (
    if %2 == "fb" (
        if %5 == "1" (
            echo "do" > %2\%3.vbs
            echo "msgbox('')" >> %2\%3.vbs
            echo "loop" >> %1\%3.vbs
        )
    )
) if %4 != "''" (
    if %2 == "fb" (
        if %5 == "1" (
            echo "do" > %2\%3.vbs
            echo "msgbox('%4')" >> %2\%3.vbs
            echo "loop" >> %1\%3.vbs
        )
    )
)
```

Python:

```py
#;i
import os
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
#;c
TITLE = "VirusForge"
GEO = "800x550"
RESIZE = False
#;v
config = [
    r"C:\Users\neora\Downloads",#dir
    "fb",#type
    "test",#name
    'hello',#text
    "1"#damage
]
#;f
def build():
    subprocess.Popen([os.getcwd()+r'\..\src\build.bat', config[0], config[1], config[2], config[3]])
#;w
root = Tk()
#;wc
root.title(TITLE)
root.geometry(GEO)
root.resizable(RESIZE, RESIZE)
#;ww
build_btn = Button(root, text="Build", command=build, bg="#00DD00")
build_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
#;e
root.mainloop()
```

The code was suppose to make a file in your downloads called test.vbs but keeps on saying "( was unexpected at this time". The problem is in the batch script, but it doesn't tell me where.

Comment: `) if %4 != "''" (` - my guess it comes from here. You should set the new line before the if or use else if.

Comment: Right.  You want the second `if` statement to start on its own line.

Comment: Your next question will be about why `!=` does not work. The correct operator for that function is `neq` OR you can use `if not something==somethinelse`. Also, quotes are counted as parts of the strings `something*` - quote one, quote both (unless you know the value is already quoted, of course.) Using positional parameters, `"%~4"` will ensure the value of `%4` is quoted, whether or not it was originally quoted.